# when calling browser methods on mechanize, I got an parse() error: unexpected keyword 'transport_encoding'

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to submit a form using mechanize.
But I can get any web page information from mechanize browser.
I don't know how to fix the problem....
Please help me...

Here are my code and the error result.
In the code, when calling the browser.title(), browser.select_form(), I got an error with parse error which cannot find keyword 'transport_encoding'

Code:

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cj)
browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.3"')]

response = browser.open(u'https://www.google.com/')
print(browser.title())
print(response.geturl())
print(response.info())
print(response.read())
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.select_form(name=u'Form1')
# for form in self.browser.forms():
#   print (form)
```

Error Message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Projects/DormFilter/DormCrawler/Connector.py", line 168, in <module>
    print(browser.title())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 561, in title   
    return self._factory.title
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_html.py", line 254, in title
    self.root) if self.root is not None else None
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_html.py", line 247, in root
    response, verify=False))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_html.py", line 149, in content_parser
    namespaceHTMLElements=False)
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

When I check in debug mode, 
self._factory has an object, self._factory.global_form has an object
but they occur the error.
What did I worng?

```
#[This code is an library code]
def title(self):
    ' Return title, or None if there is no title element in the document. '
    if not self.viewing_html():
        raise BrowserStateError("not viewing HTML")
    return self._factory.title

def select_form(self, name=None, predicate=None, nr=None, **attrs):
    if not self.viewing_html():
        raise BrowserStateError("not viewing HTML")
    if name is None and predicate is None and nr is None and not attrs:
        raise ValueError("at least one argument must be supplied to specify form")

    global_form = self._factory.global_form
    if nr is None and name is None and predicate is not None and predicate(
            global_form):
        self.form = global_form
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to apply mechanize 0.2.5 version. 
This version works well.

If someone faced the same problem, try to use another version.

0.2.5 is a stable version now, (2017-04-29)
http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/download.html